# Scheduled Task - Overflow

Tags: vb.net, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I have created a console application to run through the db (about 22K )records and update some values nightly.

i've added an email to myself on any errors. when running the task i get about 500 emails saying:

"Overflow" (which is what's returned by : exception.Message)

what does it mean? is it running through the db too fast? how can i fix this?

Thank you!

here is my code:

```
  For Each dataRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        curries = 0
        baseDate = Nothing
        sourceID = 0
        isotopeID = 0
        currentCat = 0
        act = 0
        cat = 0
        isoDetails = Nothing
        Try
            If (Not curries = "0") And IsNumeric(curries) Then
                A= dataRow("A")
                B= dataRow("B")
                C= dataRow("C")
                D= dataRow("D")
                act = CalculateActivity(A, B, dataRow("E"))
                cSource.UpdateDB(A, B, dataRow("E"), act, Now())

                isoDetails = cSource.GetLookUpDetails(dataRow("E"))
              cSource.UpdateCategory(sourceID, cat)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorOnUpdate(sourceID, isotopeID, ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
```

..........

```
Public Function CalculateIsotopeActivity(ByVal curries As Double, ByVal actibityDate As DateTime, ByVal isotope As String) As Double
    'reported activity * e^(-Log(2) * ((now - activity date)/365)/halflife))

    Return curries * Math.E ^ (-Math.Log(2) * (((Now.Date().Subtract(DateTime.Parse(actibityDate)).Days) / 365) / cSource.GetIsotopeLookUpDetails(isotope).HalfLife))

End Function
```

Comment: Do you perchance to anything recursively?

Comment: I Updated the question with my code.... i don't understand your question.

Comment: Is that missing " on the C= dataRow("C) intentional, or actually missing from your code?

Comment: its a typo when i copy and pasted it here. my code is good.

Comment: You might also be getting an arithmetic overflow, which means, basically, that the calculated number is too large for a double to hold. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: i thought about it, but after looking at the data, it's impossible, considering im getting so many ERROR emails :(

Comment: Well, that's what an overflow exception is - when a result is outside the range of the data type returned. I would check again, just in case, and try a bunch of random numbers from your data set.

Comment: Also - considering actually sending the entire exception (not just ex.Message, ex.Message is never useful on its own). That way you'll get the full stacktrace and can see more clearly where your error originates.

Comment: I often add data to exceptions and output that data to my error messages.  `Catch ex As Exception` `ex.Data.Add("A",A)` `...` `ErrorOnUpdate(sourceID,IsotopeID,ex)`  Then have `ErrorOnUpdate` iterate through `ex.Data`.

Comment: Why are you calling DateTime.Parse on a DateTime variable?  (actibityDate) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are getting a mathematical overflow on one of your variables. Try explicitly declaring your variables to a datatype and then parsing the data from the datarow into them. This will either clear up the errors or give you better error messages.

```
Dim curries as Double = 0
...
curries = Double.Parse(datarow("A"))
```

I would actually encourage you to eliminate all the implicit conversion by adding Option Strict On to your code and fixing every error the compiler finds.